# How can I define a variable in a VueJS v-if statement without displaying it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a template that is displayed based on a `v-if` statement. When that template is used, a certain variable needs to be set to `N/A`. I can't figure out how to do this. It seems like it should be so simple, but I've tried putting it in the `<span>` tag with `v-if` like this:

```
<span v-if="selected==='Powergrid'" Multiplier="N/A">
```

I've tried curly braces, which works but I don't actually want to display the variable, I just want to set it to `N/A`:

```
<span v-if="selectedSim==='Powergrid'">
{{Multiplier = 'N/A'}}
```

I've tried putting it in the template:

```
<span v-if="selectedSim==='Powergrid'">
  <powergridMenu 
    @Outcome="selectedOutcome = $event"
    @Threshold="outcomeThreshold = $event"
    Multiplier="N/A"
/>
```

I tried putting it in its own tag:

```
<span v-if="selectedSim==='Powergrid'">
<span Multiplier='N/A'></span>
```

I realize I can just write a method to set this variable, but it seems like I should be able to just set a variable. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a computed value, that's what it's for:

```js
export default {
  computed: {
    Multiplier() {
      return this.selectedSim==='Powergrid' ? 'N/A' : ''
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the code above is using `options api`; If you want to use `composition api`, read the [docs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/computed.html) about how to use computed properties in `composition api`.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure if this will work for me. Multiplier is a text entry field. For some options it's disabled and there is a job summary where I display their form info before they click submit. If the Multiplier is disabled I want it to display N/A. I don't think a computed property is what I want here.

Comment: @KLG52486 Then I think you can use watchers instead of computed property. take a look at the documentations [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html)

Comment: Thanks- that's exactly what I needed. "When new simulator is selected, change stuff." I had seen something about watchers but I didn't really understand it so it didn't occur to me.